# NServiceBus Upgrade from v3 to v4: OracleMessageModule.Begin() is not called

Tags: upgrade, nservicebus

Working code before upgrade. `HandleBeginMessage()` is called automatically:

```
public class OracleMessageModule : IMessageModule
{
    public OracleMessageModule()
    {
        Factory = new OracleSagaSessionFactory();
    }

    public OracleSagaSessionFactory Factory { get; set; }

    public void HandleBeginMessage()
    {
        Factory.Begin();
    }

    public void HandleEndMessage()
    {
        Factory.Complete();
    }

    public void HandleError()
    {
        Factory.Complete();
    }
}
```

Code not working anymore after upgrade to v4. `Begin()` is not called autommatically:

```
public class OracleMessageModule : UnitOfWork.IManageUnitsOfWork
{
    public OracleMessageModule()
    {
        Factory = new OracleSagaSessionFactory();
    }

    public OracleSagaSessionFactory Factory { get; set; }

    public void Begin()
    {
        Factory.Begin();
    }

    public void End(System.Exception ex = null)
    {
        Factory.Complete();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IManageUnitsOfWork are not autoregistered. You need to register your unit of work explicitly.

For more details on how to, see here:

http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/unit-of-work-in-nservicebus#registering-your-unit-of-work